File cannot be found message when knitting

I am trying to knit my file for my capstone project for a case study of Coursera. I am using R Markdown, but I continuously get this error "Cannot find the file(s): "skimr - data summary.png" " Backtrace:.
As you can see from the first image, the file exists when I used the "file exist function". but in rmarkdown, it does not recognise it when it knits
"Error in `knitr::include_graphics()`:
! Cannot find the file(s): "skimr - data summary.png"
Backtrace:

1. knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Documents/R/cyclistic_bike_share_analysis/skimr - data summary.png")".

Can anyone advise me on how to overcome this issue? Thank you.
i have checked my code several times but nothing has changed
added the full path to file and it still does not recognize the file

How are you asking for knitting?  Maybe it is being run in a context where that file is not available.  You could add getwd() to an earlier chunk to see the current directory when knitting happens, and that may give a clue.

BTW, it doesn't really make sense to put text in a PNG file.  It would be better to just copy and paste the text into your document, or even better, generate it in the document from the actual data files.

Hi @user2554330, do you mean I should use this code (img/skimr - data summary.png) instead of knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Documents/R/cyclistic_bike_share_analysis/skimr - data summary.png") when working with images?

No, I'm suggesting it as a way to figure out what is going wrong. Put it in before the error, and maybe you'll be able to see something useful.  If you can't see the result, then you should take out the include_graphics() call, just long enough to try to diagnose the problem.
